# Connect ESXI directly to Centos server for NFS datastore

Tags: centos, vmware-esxi, nfs

In my office we have a server that is running VMware ESXi 6.5.0 and a Centos 7 Server.

The plan is to set up a datastore for the VMware installation on the Centos server using an NFS share. Is it possible to set this up by directly connecting the two machines together using a crossover cable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is possible.

- Is there any reason you don't think it would work?
- Is there any reason you can't use a switch?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the reason for directly connecting the two machines instead of going through the switch is to try and keep the amount of traffic going over our network and to not slowdown other machines on the network.